# Error with Bash Script to create a Temp directory and copy some files

Tags: bash, mktemp

I am trying to create a Temp directory, copy some file into it, do some processing, and delete the directory. So far, I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

__tmpdir="mktemp -d /Users/Riwaz/support.XXXXXXXXXX" #Create temp directory; store address
cp /some_location/checkstyle.xml $__tmpdir #Copy a file into the directory
cd $__tmpdir
tar -czvf result.tar.gz *
cp result.tar.gz /Users/Riwaz/
rm $__tmpdir
```

But when I run thus using sh, I get:

```
line 7: cd: mktemp: No such file or directory
rm: mktemp: No such file or directory
rm: -d: No such file or directory
rm: /Users/Riwaz/support.XXXXXXXXXX: No such file or directory
```

which shows that mktemp statement never gets processed and variable holds the actual command and not the address. How would I make bash evaluate the command and store the address instead? I messed around with "", {}, and eval but couldn't make it work.

Comment: mktemp exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your script like below: First line is simply assignment instead you need to run it in sub shell and assign.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
__tmpdir=(mktemp -d /Users/Riwaz/support.XXXXXXXXXX) #Create temp directory; store address
cp /some_location/checkstyle.xml $__tmpdir #Copy a file into the directory
cd $__tmpdir
tar -czvf result.tar.gz ./*
cp result.tar.gz /Users/Riwaz/
rm $__tmpdir
```

Answer (score 0):

mktemp  exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs. . try something like this. Make sure you have sufficient privileges  :

```
 tempfoo=`basename $0`
           TMPFILE=`mktemp -d /tmp/${tempfoo}.XXXXXX`
           if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                   echo "$0: Can't create temp file, exiting..."
                   exit 1
           fi
```

So the script will give the stdr erro message in case of an `exit  > 0`. From here you can just do `&& cd tempfoo and echo $PWD || echo "can not access $ tempfoo"`

the rest go here ...